# Using indexes in the aggregation framework - understanding the documentation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I was reading the MongoDB documentation and more precisely, the aggregation pipeline.
When I read this [chapter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance) and more precisely this sentence :

> > Even when the pipeline uses an index, aggregation still requires access to the actual documents; i.e. indexes cannot fully cover an aggregation pipeline.

I don't understand very well what this sentence means. Are they saying it can use the index to the first stage but after it's not possible to use it? So why the index cannot fully cover an aggregation pipeline?

Can someone give me a very good and easy example that I can understand and an counter-example?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Aggregation framework cannot, at this time, perform covered queries: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries

Comment: Ok, but why in my chapter I was reading, it's written : "Changed in version 2.6: In previous versions, for very select use cases, an index could cover a pipeline."?

Comment: Yeah they broke it in 2.6 and have since to fix it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12015?jql=project%20%3D%20SERVER%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Aggregation%20Framework%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22covered%20index%22

Comment: @Sammaye makes an important point. The query and indexing API is "majorly" re-factored as of the 2.6 release. A lot of things have changed in an effort to unify API for different types of index usage mainly. So the same type of optimization that used to apply presently does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes a little understanding of what a "covered index" query in MongoDB actually is, and many people get this wrong. Take the following document:

```js
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```

The mistake most people make is that even when both of those fields are added to an index, as in:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "a": 1, "b": 1 })
```

Then they think this results in a "covered index" query:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": 1, "b": 2 }).explain(); // bah-wah!!!
```

But it does not. The reason being basically that as a "schema-less" data store, MongoDB has no way of knowing that "a" and "b" are actually the only fields present in every document in the collection. So without a "projection" operation that also excludes the `_id` field that was not present in the index, then the optimizer cannot possibly know the index contains all of the information it needs to retrieve this data. Therefore it has to go back to the collection unless you do this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "a": 1, "b": 2 },{ "_id": 0, "a": 1, "b": 1 }).explain(); // success!!!
```

So how does this apply to aggregation? Well as different "pipeline" stages, there is no actual way to really do the same sort of combination as is shown above. The only thing you can do is basically this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "a": 1, "b": 2 } },
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "a": 1, "b": 1 } }
])
```

The important thing is to thing "unix pipe" or `|` in "chaining" commands, so even with some optimization, this is not really the same. Each pipeline stage "passes on" the output from the proceeding stage, and this means that `_id` ( for example here ) is not actually "extracted" from the previous `$match` in an optimized way, even though you told it to "go away".

Since **`$match`** and other special stages such as **`$geoNear`** are really the only things that can actually access an index, then since the "field exclusion" is not really available you don't really get the "covered index" results.

The final thing to say here is that aggregation is not really a "drop in replacement" for a basic query and should not be used as such. You should already accept that you are "doing more work here", and that a "covered index" is not really what you want as you typically want more data than what in in the index anyway.

If it's all in the index then it probably is not really an aggregation operation and would be better performed with a basic `.find()`, even if that means re-structuring your schema representation.